# How do I scrape pdf and html from search results without obvious url

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pdf, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the pdfs and htmls from the search results from this page: http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/speeches/search-result?search-type=advanced&speaker=Lee%20Kuan%20Yew and iterate across the 67 pages of results, but there does not seem to be an easy way to find the related urls.

The basic BeautifulSoup code does not seem to be able to extract the pdfs, and I'm not sure how to iterate across the search results.

```
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/speeches/search-result"

#If there is no such folder, the script will create one automatically
folder_location = r'\Desktop\oldman'
if not os.path.exists(folder_location):os.mkdir(folder_location)

response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")     
for link in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
    #Name the pdf files using the last portion of each link which are unique in this case
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

I would normally expect a folder containing the pdfs, but this code doesn't work for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is making POST request with search term and server returns a response - a HTML page with results.

This script will go through all results and prints all `.pdf` links found on page. The search term is in variable `search_term`, in this example case it's set to `health`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/speeches/search-result'

search_term = 'health'

data = {
    'keywords': search_term,
    'search-type': 'basic',
    'keywords-type': 'all',
    'page-num': 1
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).text, 'lxml')

cnt = 1
while True:

    print()
    print('Page no. {}'.format(cnt))
    print('-' * 80)

    for a in soup.select('a[href$=".pdf"]'):
        print(a['href'])

    if soup.select_one('span.next-10'):
        data['page-num'] += 10
        cnt += 1
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).text, 'lxml')
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
Page no. 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc/20160727009/Speech%20for%20WSHC%20Chairman%20for%20WSH%20Awards%202016.pdf
http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc/20160727009/Annex%20A%20-%20Factsheet%20on%20WSH%20Awards%202016.pdf
http://www.nas.gov.sg/archivesonline/data/pdfdoc/20160727009/Annex%20B%20-%20Factsheet%20on%20Train-the-Trainer%20programme.pdf

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting this response 3 years ago. The website has been updated and this approach doesn't seem to work anymore. Would you like to have a go at it again?

Comment: @user3081750 Feel free to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.